Existence of linear transformation between $ \mathbb Q[X]$ and $ \mathbb R$ over the field $ \mathbb Q$
So the question is...
Consider $\mathbb Q[x] $ and $ \mathbb{R} $ as vector spaces over $ \mathbb{Q} $. Which of the following statements are true?

There exists an injective $ \mathbb{Q} $-linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}[x] $.
There exists an injective $ \mathbb{Q} $-linear transformation $ T: \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{R} $.
The $ \mathbb{Q} $-vector spaces $ \mathbb Q[x] $ and $ \mathbb{R} $ are isomorphic.
There do not exist non-zero $ \mathbb{Q} $-linear transformations $ T: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}[x] $.

We can easily discard statements 1 and 3 by arguing based on cardinality.
However, I am uncertain if there exists any linear transformation between $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ Q[x] $. Moreover, I haven't found any explicit injective $ \mathbb{Q} $-linear transformation from $\mathbb  Q[x] $ to $ \mathbb{R} $. While $ \mathbb{R} $ is a vector space over $ \mathbb{Q} $, this does not necessarily imply surjectivity either.
Could I get any suggestions or hints regarding whether such transformations exist?

Sorry, I am new to the site I made correction you can check that.

For $2$, this can be quite explicitly written down: just fix a transcendental number $r$ and evaluate a given polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ at $x = r$. This yields an injective $\mathbb{Q}$-linear $T: \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$. As for $4$, the existence of such a $T$ depends on the axiom of choice, so no explicit example can be given. But given the axiom of choice, a nonzero $\mathbb{Q}$-linear $T: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}[x]$ does exist, which can be constructed by choosing a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and send some basis element to something nonzero.

@DavidGao As a consequence of axiom of choice, there is a complementary subspace $V$ such that $\mathbb R = \mathbb Q \oplus V$. Define $T$ such that it acts as identity on $\mathbb Q$ and as the zero map on $V$. Does this work?

@Nothingspecial Sure, that also works.
